# Multiple messages as Azure function Ouput parameter

Tags: azure-functions

It's quite simple to define a output parameter to be inserted in a queue but I have a function that will return multiple messages that I need to insert in a queue.

I'm doing this by adding to the queue directly in the function but I wonder if there is a way of passing multiple messages as an output parameter and what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: What kind of queue are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can change the type of output binding from `out T` to `ICollector<T>` or `IAsyncCollector<T>` and then call `collector.Add` or `collector.AddAsync` respectively as many times as you want:

```cs
[FunctionName("CollectorQueueOutput")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
    [Queue("101functionsqueue")] ICollector<Customer> queueCollector)
{
    queueCollector.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "John" });
    queueCollector.Add(new Customer { FirstName = "Mark" });
}
```

See [Writing multiple output values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#writing-multiple-output-values).

Comment: Yep! This looks like it's it!

Comment: Now on version 2.0 an error shows saying "Cannot apply attribute class Queue<T> because it's generic. Any workaround for this?

Comment: whats the difference between ICollector and IAsyncCOllector?

Comment: `ICollector`' has sync methods while `IAsyncCollector` allows to `await`. Your choice depends on whether your Azure function returns a `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do that in the different programming languages:

### Azure Queue storage

**C# Script**

```cs
public static void Run(
    CustomQueueMessage input, 
    ICollector<CustomQueueMessage> myQueueItems, 
    ILogger log)
{
    myQueueItems.Add(input);
    myQueueItems.Add(new CustomQueueMessage { PersonName = "You", Title = "None" });
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
module.exports = function(context) {
    context.bindings.myQueueItem = ["message 1","message 2"];
    context.done();
};
```

**PowerShell**

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

# Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$message = @("message1", "message2")
Push-OutputBinding -Name Msg -Value $message
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = 200
    Body = "OK"
})
```

**Python**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import typing

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, msg: func.Out[typing.List[str]]) -> func.HttpResponse:

    msg.set(['one', 'two'])

    return 'OK'
```

### Azure Service Bus

**C# Script**

```cs
public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, IAsyncCollector<string> outputSbQueue)
{
    string message = $"Service Bus queue messages created at: {DateTime.Now}";
    log.LogInformation(message); 
    await outputSbQueue.AddAsync("1 " + message);
    await outputSbQueue.AddAsync("2 " + message);
}
```

**Javascript**

```js
module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    var message = 'Service Bus queue message created at ' + timeStamp;
    context.log(message);   
    context.bindings.outputSbQueue = [];
    context.bindings.outputSbQueue.push("1 " + message);
    context.bindings.outputSbQueue.push("2 " + message);
    context.done();
};
```

Reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output

Comment: Regarding python, I ran into errors with `typing.List`, so ended up using the same as in the docs `func.Out [func.QueueMessage]` but passing a list when using the `.set` method