# Azure function (written in Python) only writes the last message of a list to service bus queue

Tags: python, azure, http, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I made a service bus queue in Azure and now I want a function that can receive a list of email addresses and put those on the queue.

This is my code (Python):

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, msg: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    emailaddresses = False

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        emailaddresses = req_body.get('emailaddresses')
    except ValueError:
        pass

    if emailaddresses:
        for address in emailaddresses:
            msg.set(address)
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Successfully processed the following emailaddresses: {', '.join(emailaddresses)}")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "No emailaddresses found in body. Pass a list of emailaddresses in the request body.",
             status_code=400
        )
```

And these are the bindings:
`{ "bindings": [ { "authLevel": "function", "type": "httpTrigger", "direction": "in", "name": "req", "methods": [ "post" ] }, { "type": "http", "direction": "out", "name": "$return" }, { "connection": "servicebusqqqqqqqqqqq_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS3", "name": "msg", "queueName": "emailaddresses", "direction": "out", "type": "serviceBus" } ] }`

When I test this function it runs successfully, but it only writes the last email address of the list to the service bus queue.

I made sure that the for loop really runs for each email address, so I tested that with some logging and I verified that it does. But still it only writes the last value. I think with each loop it overwrites the last value.

I saw in this post
[Multiple messages as Azure function Ouput parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199336/multiple-messages-as-azure-function-ouput-parameter)
that you can use `ICollector<T>` or `IAsyncCollector<T>` in C# for writing multiple messages. But I couldn't find any documentation for the Python equivalent. Somebody in that post also mentioned using `msg: func.Out[typing.List[str]]`, but this gave an internal server error when I tried it.

How can I adjust my code so it writes all the email addresses to the service bus queue?

Answer (score 0):

Would it work for you to directly interact with the ServiceBus yourself instead of using the Bindings?

My experience using AzureFunctions bindings has showed to be unreliable, but the use case we had it was different (many request saving payloads to ColdStorage, the result was that we were missing lot of files that were never saved) therefore we opted to handle the resource ourselves using the provided Azure SDK libraries.

I see you have access to the connection string of the ServiceBus and the topic names, [here the SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus#send-messages-to-a-queue) offers an example how to interact with it.

As far as I know they offer possibility to send messages in bulk, [here there is an example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/dffd1a608c295d843ef2035f27591d92eab12a24/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/async_samples/send_topic_async.py#L26) that could help you

Comment: I changed my code using the examples you provided and added this function:

`def set_emailaddresses_on_queue(emailaddresses: list[str]) -> None:
    with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(os.environ['servicebusqqqqqqqqqqq_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS3']) as client:
        with client.get_queue_sender(os.environ['emailaddresses']) as sender:
            messages = [ServiceBusMessage(email) for email in emailaddresses]
            sender.send_messages(messages)`

But it returns a KeyError, because it doesn't recognise 'emailaddresses' as one of the environment variables.

Comment: I also tried seeing which environment variables are available by returning `repr(os.environ)`. And after inspecting all the variables I concluded that there is no variable that refers to the emailaddresses queue. (By the way I also checked If the variables 'SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STR' and 'SERVICE_BUS_QUEUE_NAME' are there, but they aren't and also return a KeyError when you try to access them.)

Comment: @luykxpi I think here the `emailaddresses` are not an environmental variable, this is something you are trying to create after all. I have no experience with python btw, but I use Azure service bus triggered functions.